# Does $in operator has some build in memoization

Tags: mongodb, performance, memoization

I know i can search multiple values on a specific field with `$in`. What if i have for example this array:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Lets say thats our IDs we are querying for.

My question is, does mongodb query 6 times for every element or does mongodb has some build in memoization so its querying only 4 times because `2` is here 3x times so it would be unesseccary to query it again.

Comment: You can test it by creating a large collection with dummy data and querying for an array like [1, 2] and [1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 2] where there is a million or so 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `explain` helper can make this clear:

```
PRIMARY> db.collection.explain().find({a:{$in:[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]}}).next().queryPlanner

{
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test.collection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "a" : {
            "$in" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
            ]
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "EOF"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
}
```